# Clicking btn calling snackbar causes crash

Tags: xamarin.android

Firstly, this is my first time trying Xamarin (SDK Tools 26.1.1, SDK Platform Tools 28.0, SDK Build Tools 27.0.0)
Without any amendments to the sample code, the FloatingActionButton  successfully displays the Snackbar.
But after experimenting, I discovered if I add an ID to the sample TextView, the Snackbar triggered by the FAB causes a crash.

Why is that so? How can I overcome this? i.e including ID without crash

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Thanx & Rgds,
ref

- Dialog on VS:

Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException:  occurred

- Dialog on device:

[appname] has stopped

open app again

```
[add entire file as requested]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where are you adding this TextView and if you can add the whole XML file!!

Comment: @G.hakim, I did not actualy "add" it. it was already there in content_main.axml, I merely added the 'id' line.

Comment: could you show your activity_main axml file?